# Is it possible to import an API into Azure API Management through ARM templates?

Tags: azure, import, swagger, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management

I know I can create an Azure API Management instance [using Azure Resource Management templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-azure-api-management-create), but can I also import my API into it using the same templates?

The web app which provides the API is created in a previous step using the ARM templates, and the URL for the Swagger definition is known. It would make a lot of sense to also automate the import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It is available](https://twitter.com/darrel_miller/status/964009094792302594) now. See [Api Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2019-01-01/service/apis#apicreateorupdateproperties-object).

```
{
  "properties": {
    "format": "swagger-link-json",
    "value": "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
    "path": "petstore"
  }
}
```

Comment: The link is now broken but you can find the new docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/2019-01-01/service/apis#apicreateorupdateproperties-object

As of version 2019-01-01 the fields are now called `format` & `value`

Comment: My pleasure antmeehan!

Comment: Does this handle SSL certificates? My swagger is protected by a certificate.

Comment: I think it the swagger has to be accessible anonymously (your actual API can still be protected).

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported yet, but it's in the backlog. I don't have a date to share at this point.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I won't mark it as accepted, since there might be an answer posted with the actual funtioning solution, once it is implemented.

Comment: It is available now.  Here are docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/api/createorupdate#apimanagementcreateapiusingswaggerimport

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that this way of importing doesn't support versioned API's yet. To get this working you need to first run an ARM template to create a versioned API and next the ARM template containing the import.